# How can I determine ALL 'key/keyref' constraint violations of an XML document with its XSD using JAXP(xerces)

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, jaxp

I need to validate an XML against its XSD schema, where I have defined several 'key/keyref' constraints to determine all existing violations. But JAXP XML validator after first determination of such keyref violation will skip others, even if they are present.

The xml file with two keyref violations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<relations>
<keys>
    <key id="1"/>
    <key id="2"/>       
</keys>     
<refs>      
    <ref to="2"/><!-- This is valid because key with id 2 present -->

      <!-- This two xml elements have 'keyref' constraint violation because there aren't        coresponding keys with id 3,4-->
    <ref to="3"/>
    <ref to="4"/>
</refs>
</relations>
```

The xsd schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
 <xs:element name="relations">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element ref="keys"/>
    <xs:element ref="refs"/>
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
<!-- Constraints Section -->    
<xs:key name="key-pk">
    <xs:selector xpath="keys/key" />
    <xs:field xpath="@id" />
</xs:key>
<xs:keyref name="ref-key-pk" refer="key-pk">
    <xs:selector xpath="refs/ref" />
    <xs:field xpath="@to" />        
</xs:keyref>    
 </xs:element>
<xs:element name="keys">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="key"/>
  </xs:sequence>      
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="refs">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ref"/>
  </xs:sequence>      
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="key">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:long"/>      
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="ref">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:attribute name="to" type="xs:long"/>      
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Java code that performs such validation:

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import javax.xml.transform.Source;
 import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
 import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
 import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
 import javax.xml.validation.Validator;
 import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
 import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
 import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

 public class LayoutXmlValidator {

private static final String XSD = "/examp.xsd";
private File xml = null;
private Validator validator;
private Schema schema;
private ErrorHandler errorHandler;

private static class ErrorReporter implements ErrorHandler{
    private int errorCounter;       
    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        final String tag = "warning";
        out(tag, exception);        
    }       
    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        final String tag = "fatal";
        out(tag, exception);
    }       
    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {            
        final String tag = "error";
        out(tag, exception);
    }

    private void out(String tag, SAXParseException e){          
        errorCounter++;         
        String msg = e.getMessage()+"\n";
        msg +="    "+tag+" at "+e.getSystemId()+":"+e.getLineNumber();
        System.out.println(errorCounter+")"+msg);
    }
}


public LayoutXmlValidator() {
    try{
        SchemaFactory factory = 
            SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        InputStream xsd = getClass().getResourceAsStream(XSD);
        schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsd));            
        validator = schema.newValidator();
        errorHandler = new ErrorReporter();
    }catch(Throwable e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}       

public void setErrorHandler(ErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    this.errorHandler = errorHandler;
}

private void validate(){
    try{                                                                                    
        validator.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);            
        Source source = new StreamSource(xml);            
        try {                                               
            validator.validate(source);             
        }
        catch (SAXException ex) {
            System.out.println(xml + " is not valid because ");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }           
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {                                                                
    LayoutXmlValidator v = new LayoutXmlValidator();
    v.xml = new File("examp.xml");
    v.validate();                                  
}
  }
```

I expect 2 errors for `<ref to="3"/>` and `<ref to="4"/>`, but the validator can determine only the first of these errors for `<ref to="3"/>`. When i change `<ref to="3"/>` to `<ref to="2"/>` the problematic node  will determined. How can I get all of such reference errors per one xml processing ?